# Rendering Trouble

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

```
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: "<?php echo($_SESSION["total_price"]); ?>"
          }
        }]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
      });
    }
  }).render('.Paypal');
```

The button renders on a page reload but ***NOT*** when the page is first visited.

```
value: "<?php echo($_SESSION["total_price"]); ?>"
```

I have a feeling that the PHP code is not reaching its destination before it renders causing it to bug out

Any ideas?
Help is much appreciated

Comment: Try to change this: value: "<?php echo($_SESSION["total_price"]); ?>"
Into this: value: "<?php echo($_SESSION['total_price']); ?>"

Comment: Same problem. Any other ideas? Thanks!